# Bluetooth library for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, network-programming, bluetooth

Where can I find the bluetooth API details for Windows Xp, dlls etc for PAN connection etc. 
Thanks and Regards,
Anjali

Comment: Which language/Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MSDN Bluetooth" on any search engine:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932(VS.85).aspx